# attributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'MXIndexedRecordIO'

Tags: python-2.7, cpu, mxnet

I have used im2rec.py to convert "caltech101 images" into record io format:

I have created "caltech.lst" succesfully using
os.system('python %s/tools/im2rec.py --list=1 --recursive=1 --shuffle=1 data/caltech data/101_ObjectCategories'%MXNET_HOME)
Then, when I run this :
os.system("python %s/tools/im2rec.py --train-ratio=0.8 --test-ratio=0.2 --num-thread=4 --pass-through=1 data/caltech data/101_ObjectCategories"%MXNET_HOME)
I have this error : attributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'MXIndexedRecordIO'
Please, someone has an idea to fix this error ?
Thanks in advance.

Environment info

Operating System:Windows 8.1

MXNet version:0.9.5

Answer (score 1):

If I have found the right version of `im2rec.py` then the program is failing at one of the two calls that look like this:

```
record = mx.recordio.MXIndexedRecordIO(...)
```

That looks very much as if the code you are running is expecting a different version of `mxnet` from the one you have installed. The message is telling you that there isn't a class/function called `MXIndexedRecordIO` in module `mxnet.recordio`.

Comment: I have used tools/im2rec.py included in mxnet.0.9.5 package

Comment: I'm no `mxnet` expert. I'm just explaining what the message means.

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules. I have tested other versions of mxnet and i had the same error :(

Comment: That's probably some python binding error on window. Did you try the im2rec binary? Does it work for your case?
You can follow the tutorial here: http://mxnet.io/how_to/recordio.html?highlight=im2rec

Comment: Hi, i don't have a bin repository on my mxnet package to run this: ./bin/im2rec image.lst image_root_dir output.bin resize=256

Comment: @eric-haibin-lin can you please explain me by a short example how to use im2rec binany..

Comment: @user3824903 the binary should be there after mxnet is compiled from source. Which version of mxnet are you using? How did you install mxnet?

Comment: Hi @eric-haibin-lin,I use MXNet version:0.9.5. I think that i have installed Mxnet successfully because  running  "import mxnet as mx" doesn't give an error and also i have converted my data to ".lst file" successfully.

Comment: Hi @eric-haibin-lin You were right, I installed mxnet incorrectly, it was missing .dll files (mingw64 and OpenBlas). now, the error has disappeared. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@user3824903 I think to create a bin directory, you have to compile MXNet from source with option USE_OPENCV=1

Comment: @ Roshani Nagmote What did you mean "from Source" please? can you give me an example with the  line command to use.

Comment: I meant cloning mxnet repository then, running this command:  "make -j  USE_OPENCV=1"  in mxnet repo. I haven't tried it on Windows though. Works fine on Mac